# Passing an already initiated instance of a base class?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that inherits another class as its base class, so like.

```
class Player : PlayerData
{
    public Player(IChannelHandlerContext context) : base()
    {
    }
}
```

When initiating class `Player` is there a way I can give the class my already created instance of PlayerData? It seems a waste to create one and then have to create it all again?

Comment: Do you want to cast an instance of the `Player` type to `PlayerData` type?

Comment: I already have an instance of `PlayerData` class, I'm wondering if I would somehow pass this instance in (using `base` or some kind of mechanism) when I create my instance of `Player` class.

Comment: You could add constructor that accepts an instance of the base class and copy it properties to the current instance.

Comment: @Alexander The 2 answers have suggested this, although neither work.

Comment: What’s the natural relation between Playerdata and Player? Could a player not *have a* PlayerData rather than *be a* PlayerData? Inheritance is rarely the right tool. If the Player stores the PlayerData in a field and both types implement a new interface “IPlayerData” exposing e.g “PlayerId” from both types - would that no make it more manageable?

Comment: I have answered the ways to achieve this, there is no more mystery here, you need to copy the properties, there is no other solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it as the parameter in constructor.

```
PlayerData pd = new PlayerData();
Player p = new Player(chanelHandlerContext, pd);
```

if that what you mean. If you want Player instance to have already been populated with the property values from the instance of the base class, you better use Automapper for it.

Just try this, works fine:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PlayerData pd = new PlayerData();
            IChannelHandlerContext chanelHandlerContext = new ChannelHandlerContext();
            Player p = new Player(chanelHandlerContext, pd);
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }

        interface IChannelHandlerContext
        {

        }

        class ChannelHandlerContext : IChannelHandlerContext
        {

        }

        class PlayerData
        {

        }

        class Player : PlayerData
        {
            public Player(IChannelHandlerContext context, PlayerData pd) : base()
            {
            }
        }
```

This way also will work fine:

```
class PlayerData
        {
            public PlayerData()
            {

            }

            public PlayerData(PlayerData pd)
            {

            }
        }

        class Player : PlayerData
        {
            public Player(IChannelHandlerContext context, PlayerData pd) : base(pd)
            {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is called *Downcasting* and it just cant be done with a instantiate base type to a more specific type. However you can :

1. Pass it in as a constructor parameter and copy over the base properties
2. Use method or if you are really committed reflection to copy over the base properties
3. Or if you really wanted to go down this rabbit hole you could potentially use *Automapper* to create and map to your new derived type (`Player`)

Comment: Class `PlayerData` doesn't have a parameterless constructor so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can give you instance of `PlayerData` as an argument to the constructor of `Player`. If your base class has a copy constructor you can pass the argument to the base constructor.

```
class PlayerData
{
    public int _dataParameter;

    public PlayerData(int parameter)
    {
        _dataParameter = parameter;
    }

    protected PlayerData(PlayerData pd)
    {
        _dataParameter = pd._dataParameter;
    }
}

class Player : PlayerData
{
    public int _playerParameter;

    public Player(int a, PlayerData pd) : base(pd)
    {
        _playerParameter = a;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pd = new PlayerData(1);
        var p = new Player(2, pd);

        Console.WriteLine("Player {0}, base {1}", p._playerParameter, p._dataParameter);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Other solution would be not to derive from `PlayerData` but to keep an instance of `PlayerData` in your `Player` object (composition instead of inheritance).

Comment: Class `PlayerData` doesn't have a parameterless constructor so this won't work.

Comment: Where would you Need a parameterless constructor? As argument you pass an already existing object, the pass to the copy constructor get's also an already existing object?
`var pd = new PlayerData(....); var p = new Player(context, pd);`

Comment: Your code simply states `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'X' of 'PlayerData.PlayerData(parameters here)`

Comment: I expented the code fragment to a working example. `Player` has one parameter for it's own  and gets an instance of `PlayerData` which is based to the base class. Transfer to `IChannelHandlerContext` and you spefici `PlayerData` class is left for you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your specific question -

> Passing an already initiated instance of a base class?

**No**. Creating an instance of `Player` type means first creating instance of base type i.e. `PlayerData` and is non-isolated unit of operation.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion, pass the instance of base class to your derived class, to inherit not just the properties, but including the values:

```
public class PlayerData
{
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }
}

public class Player : PlayerData
{
    public Player(PlayerData pd) : base()
    {
        this.PlayerID = pd.PlayerID;
    }
}
```

Then whenever you declare your derived class, pass the base class that you want to inherit:

```
PlayerData pd = new PlayerData()
        {
            PlayerID = 1
        };

        Player p = new Player(pd);
```

Then the value of:

> p.PlayerID

is also 1. Without using declaring any value properties on Player instance.